# How to create a chrome/brave desktop shortcut on linux

Tags: linux, chrome

I am trying to create a desktop shortcut in brave (basically the same thing as chrome). I can get the separate window by clicking menu -> more tools -> create shortcut, but it does not create a desktop shortcut for easy access.

This is what I am trying,

1. go to the site
2. click menu -> more tools -> create shortcut
3. check the "open as window" box and click create

When I do this, it opens the app in a separate window but does not create a .desktop file for quick access. Is there a way to do this in linux? I can setup my own desktop file if I knew where the executable for the pwa is located, but I'm not sure on that either.

Comment: I just installed brave, and the act of `"install xxx mobile application..."` created the appropriate desktop shortcut - perhaps your PWA is NOT an actual PWA? i.e. when you go to the PWA page, do you get the option to "install ... mobile application" in brave menu?

Comment: Let's use apple music as an example (https://music.apple.com/subscribe), I can create an `app` and then when I go to `brave://apps` or `chrome://apps` I can see it there. When I right click on the app and click `create shortcuts..` It doesn't create a `.desktop` file.

Comment: Oh, right - what desktop environment are you running, and what linux distro? also, WHERE are you doing `click menu -> more tools -> create shortcut`? in the browser?

Comment: gnome, ubuntu 22.04, yes in the browser

Comment: does gnome even show desktop shortcuts? (I admit, I don't dabble with gnome very much - but my one gnome install has no desktop icons at all)

Comment: it does not have desktop icons, but there are `.desktop` files which are in the `Show Applications` menu.

Comment: yes, and that doesn't work for you? Does for me, after I "Install xxx mobile application"of course - `music.apple.com/subscribe` doesn't look like it's a PWA anyway - websites aren't PWA's, they have to be created AS a PWA to work like one

Comment: so are you creating it in a different way than `menu -> more tools -> create shortcut...`? This is what does not work for me.

Comment: well, I'm "Installing a PWA" using "`Install xxx mobile application`" (xxx is the name of the app) ... which is NOT an option at the link you provided, since that is NOT a PWA, it's just a plain ol' website - perhaps you don't understand what a PWA is ...

Comment: yes, pwa is not an option for apple music, modified question to not include pwa.

Comment: then create a shortcut that's just `/path/to/browser https://url.....` pretty sure brave will take a URL on the command line (obviously `path/to/browser` is where ever  brave executable is)

Comment: this works most of the time but for some reason not for plex.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using nativefier as a decent solution.
https://github.com/nativefier/nativefier

This packages up a website as an app and gives you an executable, you can then create your `.desktop` file pointing to that executable to create the shortcut.